# What is wrong with my approach in converting a complex equation into polar form?

Tags: complex-numbers, polar-coordinates

The equation I wanted to convert was $|z^2-1|=1$. This is a very easy example but I have no idea where I made my mistake.

Putting $z=re^{i\theta}$, we have $z^2=r^2e^{2i\theta}$. Square both sides on the equation above and use the fact that $|z|^2=z\bar{z},$ we have
$$1=|r^2e^{2i\theta}-1|^2=(r^2e^{2i\theta}-1)(\overline{r^2e^{2i\theta}-1})=(r^2e^{2i\theta}-1)({r^2e^{-2i\theta}-1})=r^4-r^2e^{-2i\theta}-r^2e^{2i\theta}+1.$$

So this gives, (either $r=0$ or) $r^2=e^{-2i\theta}+e^{2i\theta}=2\cos(2\theta).$

However, naturally I though this should corresponds to ($r=0$ or) $r=2\cos(\theta).$ (which can be obtained via $z=x+iy$)

This should be relatively easy but I have no idea why two methods dont agree.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: in general, $(2\cos(\theta))^2\ne2\cos(2\theta)$

Comment: No error. Why do you think it should correspond to $r=2\cos\theta$?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner I think that's the point. They find the solution $r^2 = 2\cos(2\theta)$, but believe that the solution _ought_ to be $r = 2\cos\theta$.

Comment: Why do you think it should be $r=2\cos\theta$?

Comment: \begin{align}1=|z^2-1|^2
&=|(x+iy)^2-1|^2\\
&=|(x^2-y^2-1)+2xyi|^2\\
&=(x^2-y^2-1)^2+4x^2y^2\\
&=(r^2\cos2\theta-1)^2+r^4\sin^22\theta\\
&=r^4-2r^2\cos2\theta+1
\end{align}
same as asker's working.

Comment: Thank you everyone! I made such a silly mistake in thinking this has to be some circle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, notice that ${|z^2 - 1|=1}$ would imply that ${z^2-1}$ lies on the complex unit circle. So ${\Re(z^2 - 1)=\cos(\theta)}$, and ${\Im(z^2-1)=\sin(\theta)}$ (since ${\cos(\theta) + i\sin(\theta)}$ describes the complex unit circle). You also know from simple algebraic manipulation that

$${z^2-1 = [\Re(z)^2 - \Im(z)^2 - 1] + [2\Re(z)\Im(z)]i}$$

And so you get a system of equations

$${\begin{array}{cc}\Re(z)^2 - \Im(z)^2 - 1 &=\cos(\theta)\\2\Re(z)\Im(z)&=\sin(\theta)\end{array}}$$

Which, for a given value of ${\theta}$ - is enough to deduce the value(s) of ${z \in \mathbb{C}}$.